# Creating an iOS app with Xcode that runs on M2 Macbook Air

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to use Xcode to create a stand-alone iOS app that runs on my M2 MacBook Air.

I'm developing an iOS app using Xcode (15.0.1) on a M2 MacBook Air (macOS Sonoma 14.0).  When I set the project destination as my iPhone, Xcode builds an app that lives and runs on my phone.  But if I choose Xcode/Product menu/Destination/Mac = “My Mac (Designed for iPad)”, Xcode builds an app running on my laptop with my custom icon in the Dock.  Just terrific!  Question: does that app now live somewhere on my laptop as an executable file that I can move and copy and double-click to run...or it just an ephemeral program the requires Xcode for life support?  If the latter, is there something I can do to convert it into the former?  (Must I run it through the App Store or TestFlight before I can download it to my Mac as a verified iOS app?)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean:

> can I run the app without Xcode running, the answer is: probably yes.

If you mean:

> can I delete Xcode and run with out it, or can I copy it to a friend's computer, the answer is: maybe, but you shouldn't.

You don't need to use TestFlight or the App Store for distribution, but you should use a form of distribution that Apple provides via Xcode and its tool chain.

There's a brief comment on this here: [Outside the Mac App Store](https://developer.apple.com/macos/distribution/), it is not explicit about "Designed for iPad".

The key choice is probably [Select a method for distribution](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-your-app-for-beta-testing-and-releases#Select-a-method-for-distribution). Keep in mind the "Designed for <>" (iPad and iOS running on macOS/Apple-Silicon) is a new thing. The documentation has improved over the years, but may not cover this explicitly.

Comment: To be more specific, I'm wondering if I can create a standalone iOS app (i.e. an executable file) that runs on my Mac...just like the standalone app that runs on my iPhone.  Setting Xcode's destination to "My Mac" generates a running application, but no actual executable file that I can find to run art some later time.

Comment: Probably, but I would recommend TestFlight as the best starting option. The other forms of distribution are somewhat specialized, and I get the sense you are new to the platform. (For one thing, apps's aren't files, they are actually directories (Apple calls them "bundles").